# what persistent scope to use in absence of session scope

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I need to maintain a variable in persistent scope, that is until user session is active. Problem is application does not allow session management and it is not possible to change that. 
I want to display a message to the user only once in logged in session. What are my options except session and if possible except using DB.

Comment: Please explain the apparent contradiction between not allowing session management and "display a message to the user only once in logged in session"

Comment: Agreed. If you have the ability to login a user, then you must have session management enabled. If not, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that you may have misunderstood the session scope.  A user doesn't need to be logged in to have a session.  Normally* a user would keep the same session before and after being logged in.
*Obviously there are cases where deliberately destroying the session before logging someone in is sensible, it's not something I've seen very often

Comment: Wow, someone is really limiting your options here. You should tell the person that told you not to use the session scope or a database table to build you a house but they cannot use nails and they cannot use screws.

Comment: I think I made it bit complex. Logged in users are managed through client scope. It is not a public site. By displaying once in "user session" I did not meant CF session, but the generic duration user stays on the application.

Comment: Surely you can display the message and then once they have seen it store something in their client scope to say they have seen the message and if they have that set don't show them the message again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very long comment.  It won't answer the question but it might give the questioner some ideas.

I wrote and still maintain a ColdFusion application that has sesssion management set to false.  This app displays html content inside a desktop application - not a web browser.  Security is handled by the desktop application.  If you can log into that application and are the appropriate type of user, you can access the html content.

On the ColdFusion side, the possibility of someone discovering the url and trying to access the site with a web browser must be handled.  That's done with data.  The desktop application puts a UUID into a database and sends it as a url variable.  ColdFusion checks to see if the UUID exists and is sufficiently recent.  If that check fails, the user is sent to a "shame on you for trying" page.  This is done in the onRequestStart method of Application.cfc

Other relevent variables are sent to ColdFusion from the same database record as the UUID, but they could conceivably also be url variables.  The onRequestStart method copies these variables to the request scope which is used in the other ColdFusion pages.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a session cookie using `cfcookie` that doesn't use the `expires` attribute.  This would cause the cookie to expire when the user closes the browser.  Your cookie would indicate whether or not the message has been displayed.

```
<cfif structkeyexists(cookie, "message_displayed") eq false>
     <cfcookie name="message_displayed" value="true"/>
     <p>Your Message Here</p>
</cfif>
```